# Input only working once in Android

Tags: java, android, input

A question (ID 1606993) like this was posted, but didn't really answer mine, so here goes:

In an app for Android that I am creating, the user must input numbers from the keypad for the app to continue. When they are done entering their numbers, they can either press the return key or the main button. Problem is, its only working once.

Here is my listening method:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int key, KeyEvent event)//Listens for key events
{
    if(key==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0)
        add(0);
    else if(key==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1)
        add(1);
    else if(key==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2)
        add(2);
    else if(key==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3)
        add(3);
    else if(key==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_4)
        add(4);
    else if(key==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5)
        add(5);
    else if(key==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_6)
        add(6);
    else if(key==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_7)
        add(7);
    else if(key==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_8)
        add(8);
    else if(key==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9)
        add(9);
    else if(key==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
        setNum();
    else if(key==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
        setNum();
    return true;
}
```

The add(int numb) method adds num to the text field that takes up the screen, its not causing any problems.

Here is setNum() :

```
protected void setNum()//Sets the number and tells the Runner it is set.
{
    if(ray.size()==1)
        num=ray.get(0);
    else if(ray.size()==0)
        num=0;
    else
        num=(ray.get(0)*10)+ray.get(1);
    ray=new ArrayList<Integer>();//or ray.clear(), I've tried both
    ready=true;
}
```

ArryayList ray is where the numbers are stored. The computation is working fine.
Int num is the number that the code uses. Boolean ready is there because in the runner class there is a while loop waiting for ready to be true to continue the code.

```
while(!a.ready)
{
    for(int x=0;x<100;x++);
}
```

Any ideas?

Edit: Here is the method in Runner that is called:

```
while(!go)
    {
        addText("It is White's move");
        addText("Possible pieces to move");
        for(int x=0;x<b.getWhite().getPiecesWithMoves(b).size();x++)//Loop to print White's pieces that can move
        {
            addText(""+(x+1)+") "+b.getWhite().getPiecesWithMoves(b).get(x));
        }   
        got=false;
        p=0;
        while(!got)//Loop to enter number
        {
            addText("Input the number of the piece you want to move");
            while(!a.ready)
            {
                for(int x=0;x<100;x++);
            }
            p=a.num-1;
            if(p<b.getWhite().getPiecesWithMoves(b).size()&&p>=0)//Checks to make sure that p is valid
                got=true;
            a.num=0;
            a.ready=false;
        }
        gl=b.getWhite().getPiecesWithMoves(b).get(p).getLocation();//Makes a location that is where the piece currently is
        addText("Possible moves");
        for(int x=0;x<b.getPiece(gl).getMoves(b).size();x++)//Loop to print where the piece can go
        {
            addText(""+(x+1)+") "+b.genL(b.getPiece(gl).getMoves(b).get(x)));
        }
        got=false;//reset
        while(!got)//Loop to enter number
        {
            addText("Input the number of one of these moves.");
            addText("If you wish to change, enter 0.");
            while(!a.ready)
            {
                for(int x=0;x<100;x++);
            }
            p=a.num-1;
            if(p==-1)
                got=true;
            else if(p<b.getPiece(gl).getMoves(b).size()&&p>=0)//Checks to make sure that p is valid
            {
                got=true;
                go=true;
            }
            a.num=0;
            a.ready=false;
        }
    }
    gk=b.getPiece(gl).getMoves(b).get(p);//The location that the piece is going to
    b.move(gk, b.getPiece(gl),gk.isTaken(),gk.isCastle());//Moves the piece
```

Comment: whats the point of the runner loop?  Won't it just exist as an infinite loop?  Or is it in an asynchronous thread?  A better way to handle events like that would be with a broadcast receiver

Comment: What part is not working the second time? Error? Exception? Wrong number? No number? Infinite loop? Demons?

Comment: @John: I tried pausing it to wait for a message from the main Activity but that started throwing Interrupted exceptions. The Runner class does send messages to the main class, if that helps at all.

Comment: @Ishtar: It simply doesn't work. You can press either key on the emulator as many times as you want and nothing will happen. The other number keys still work fine, and still add text to the screen, but the return and main keys don't.

Comment: try debugging the setNum function, to see what's inside ray.  Just launch the app in debug mode on your device with a breakpoint set at the top of the if statement

Comment: Try the debugger.  If numbers are going in but the `enter` key isn't, then it should be a problem with your code.  I don't think we have enough of your code here to find the real problem.

Comment: @Haphazard: How much code is appropriate for StackOverflow?

Comment: As much as is necessary.  We're here to help.

Comment: @Travis - I think the Runner is at fault. The busy wait (`while(!a.ready){...}`) is not the best way to wait on a condition. What purpose has the Runner? If you need to calculate something in the background after a number was entered, there are more robust solutions.

Comment: @Ishtar: The Runner at that point is waiting for the user to input a number that it uses once the user presses enter. The various ways of stopping a Thread, 'pause()' 'suspend()' 'wait()', didn't work. How would you get it to wait for another class to do something?

Comment: post more code.  what kind of View are you using?

Comment: OK, I added the whole method in the Runner class that is actually doing the work. addText sends a message to the Activity telling it to add text to the TextView

Comment: @Travis - Aha, problem is clear to me now. You are reading `a.num` and `a.ready` in the Runner and set them in setNum() in the GUI thread, right? Hmmmm, this is not the correct approach for GUI programming. One minute, let me think of a correct solution...

Comment: Thanks to everyone who gave me ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyView {
  int num;
  int currentState = 1; //much, much more pretty if you'd use Enum, 
                        //but I'll keep it simple now.

  public boolean onKeyDown(int key, KeyEvent event) {
    //no changes here
  }

  protected void setNum(){
    if(ray.size()==1)
        num=ray.get(0);
    else if(ray.size()==0)
        num=0;
    else
        num=(ray.get(0)*10)+ray.get(1);
    ray=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (currentState == 1) //(TODO:should really use Enum here....)
       part1();
    else if (currentState == 2)
       part2();
    else if (...
  }

  void part1() {
    addText("It is White's move");
    addText("Possible pieces to move");
    for(int x=0;x<b.getWhite().getPiecesWithMoves(b).size();x++)
    {
      addText(""+(x+1)+") "+b.getWhite().getPiecesWithMoves(b).get(x));
    }

    addText("Input the number of the piece you want to move");
    currentState = 2;//now we do nothing, we wait untill user finishes input
  }
  void part2()
  {//will be called after part1 finishes and a number has been entered
    p=a.num-1;
    if(p<b.getWhite().getPiecesWithMoves(b).size()&&p>=0) {
      gl=b.getWhite().getPiecesWithMoves(b).get(p).getLocation();
      addText("Possible moves");
      //and more code
      //Need input? stop and set next entry point
      currentState = 3;//continue to part 3
    }
    else
    {
      addText("Input the number of the piece you want to move");
      currentState = 2;//oops, stay at part2, we didn't get a good number!
    }
  }

}
```

The idea is to do nothing when the user has to input. There is no code running at that moment, for example after part1() finishes. When the user finishes input and presses a key, you have to make sure the correct code then executes, part2 gets called then. And then just stop running code when you need input again.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Ishtar, this makes a lot more sense than what I was doing!